# USB UDF is there a way to format to Fat32

Tags: usb, partitioning, format, fat32, udf

I found a old USB that has two partitions. One is Fat32 and the other CD Drive UDF.
I can't seem to find a way online on how to delete a UDF partition. So maybe here I can find a possible solution?

Fat32: 800MB
UDF: 40 MB
Total USB should be 2GB

I already tried using the disk manager. But I can't find a way to format the UDF partition.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of Disk Management?

Comment: Hello Daniel B, here are the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/CqqNcGz

Comment: Why are you think it's really 2GB? Anyway, this is easily handled in Linux (dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/flash and it's filled with zeros, without any partition table). Also, thank you for a method to fool windows users :D

Comment: Hello Nikita, I'm sorry I forgot to specify, my OS is Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible.
Many of these USB sticks with a fake CD partition announce themselves to the OS as 2 separate devices: A USB harddisk and a USB CD-drive.
If that is the case you just can't change it yourself. In some cases there is a utility from the USB stick manufacturer available that can change it back into a single device stick.

If it appears to your OS as a single device with 2 partitions (which would be highly unusual) any partitioning software (Windows Disk Administrator or DiskPart, GPartED, good old FDISK, MacOS DiskUtility) should be able to delete the UDF partition.